# MySQL server going down on some queries

Tags: mysql

We have a MySQL database hosted in a private SQL (OVH) with 256MB RAM (MySQL 5.7). The database size is 3 GB and we are using Innodb storage engine.

The problem is that the server crashes on some queries without delay. We see the `Server has gone away` error.

```
SELECT `A`.* FROM `A` 
LEFT JOIN `B` ON `A`.`IDB` = `B`.`ID` 
WHERE ((`A`.`IDL`=74) 
AND ((status in ("V","O") or (status = "C" and IDBy = 1)))) 
AND (`B`.`IDL`=74) ORDER BY `B`.`note` DESC LIMIT 10
```

The A table contains ~60000 rows and the B table ~920000 rows.

We had the same problem (the server to go down) with `Select count(*) from B`. So I converted it from InnoDB to MyISAM and now the count is good.

The question is : Is it the size of the memory (256 MB) who is not sufficient for the database or is it some other reason?

Comment: Check the server logs to get a better sense of what's going on.

Comment: You might try removing some of the unnecessary `()` you seem to have sprayed all over this query

Comment: Can you please provide the output of an EXPLAIN on that query? Additionally: Could it be that the connection to the Server just dropped because of timeouts (waiting too long for data)? see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html for details

Comment: to Olli : the server is crashing immediately after executing the query so i think the timeout is not involved.

Comment: to RiggsFolly : I removed unnecessary () from the query but still got the same result : #1053 - Server shutdown in progress